# Como fazer com que o R repita uma requisição?

Tags: r

Estou tentando extrair dados do Vagalume pelo R, para isso, utilizei o pacote "vagalumeR", e tirei um exemplo de código daqui: https://brunaw.github.io/vagalume/vagalumeR.html

O problema: ao tentar extrair as letras das música de determinados artista eu recebo um erro, quase sempre, mas nem sempre, o que me faz presumir que o erro seja fruto de uma instabilidade da API. sendo assim, gostaria de saber como fazer com que o R repita a solicitação até que a letra seja de fato extraida.

```
library(vagalumeR)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
artist <- "portela"
song <- songNames(artist)
let <- ldply(map(song$song.id[1:62], lyrics, type = "id",
                 key = key), data.frame)
```

> Error in if (cont$mus[[1]]$lang > 1) { : argument is of length zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tentar até conseguir

A seguinte solução não é nem eficiente nem elegante, mas faz o que você pediu.

```
lyrics2 <- function(x, type, key) {
  # Tenta pegar dados
  res <- try(lyrics(x, type = type, key = key))
  if (inherits(res, 'try-error')) { # verifica se houve erro
    cat('Um erro ocorreu com a música de id:', as.character(x), '\n')
    Sys.sleep(abs(rnorm(1, 2)))
    return(lyrics2(x, type, key)) # faz chamada recursiva
  }
  res # retorna resultado caso não haja erro
}
```

A ideia da `lyrics2` é basicamente tentar chamar a função e, se um erro ocorrer, chamar esta função  que verifica o erro (`lyrics2`) recursivamente. Desta maneira ela só vai parar de se chamar quando não houver mais erro na requisição.

A função `try()` tenta executar o código dentro dela mas não para caso um erro ocorra. Neste caso ela devolve um objeto com a classe 'try-error' e com a mensagem do erro.

Se um erro tiver ocorrido, a função `Sys.sleep()` põe o sistema para "dormir". O argumento passado para ela é o valor absoluto de um número aleatório, que na média será 2. A ideia de fazer isso é ser "gentil" com o servidor.

Ocorre que o código fica rodando infinitamente (ou pelo menos durante muito tempo) porque há algum problema com a API em alguns IDs (como o '3ade68b8g2009b0b3').

```
let2 <- map(song$song.id, lyrics2, type = "id", key = key)
```

## Eliminar falhas

Por este motivo, outra opções pode ser tentar executar o código uma vez e eliminar as falhas.

```
df_erro <- data.frame(
  id = 'erro', name = 'erro', song.id = 'erro',
  song = 'erro', language = NA_integer_, text = 'erro'
)
safe_lyrics <- safely(lyrics, otherwise = df_erro, FALSE)
```

O código acima usa alguns dos conceitos do pacote `purrr` (já carregado no `tidyverse`).

O primeiro deles é a ideia de uma função segura. A função `safely()` retorna a mesma função passada como primeiro argumento, mas com uma modificação: ela agora passará a retornar um resultado com duas listas. A primeira lista se chama `result` e contém o resultado caso tudo ocorra bem e a segunda se chama `error` e conterá a mensagem do erro. O segundo argumento passado é o resultado que deve retorna nos casos de erro. Ele é útil para permitir juntar os resultados posteriormente

O segundo é usar a função `map_df('result')` para mapear todas as listas que retorna do primeiro `map` para extrair o elemento 'result' delas e uni-las em um `data.frame`.

```
let3 <- map(song$song.id, safe_lyrics, type = "id", key = key) %>% 
  map_df('result')
```

O resultado acima retorna um `data.frame`  com 62 observações, uma para cada música da Portela. Os erros voltam com o conteúdo de `df_erro` e podem ser verificado com `which(let3$id == 'erro')`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! De qualquer forma, o problema não foi completamente resolvido pois não está relacionado diretamente ao erro de uma música. Uma aplicação da função safe_lyrics num conjunto de artistas retorna um diferente número de erros a cada requisição. Além disso, preciso alegar que enquanto você teve problemas coma música 4 da Portela, estou agora tendo com a 61, e a cada dia que rodo essa função a música problemática muda. Ao requerer a letra de 658 músicas, a API só me retornou 117, sendo o resto da tabela composta por erros.